# Setting Up Partitioning Table Range with Composite Key

Tags: postgresql

I am having issues with my ranges for setting up a table partition. Using first name and last name as two columns I am trying to make tables for each combination of starting letters such as A/A, A/B..., B/A, B/B, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE test.part_comp(
  first_name varchar(20) not null,
  last_name varchar(20) not null,
  age int,
  PRIMARY KEY(first_name,last_name)PARTITION BY RANGE(first_name,last_name);

CREATE TABLE test.part_comp_01 PARTITION OF test.part_comp FOR VALUES FROM
  ('A%','A%') to ('AZ%','AZ%');
```

So having an entry like 'Apple' 'Appleson' should work but 'Apple' 'Bapple' should not be inserted into this table. But upon testing it out Apple Bapple also appears within this table despite the last name column only working for values starting with 'A'. What can I do to fix the range?

Another way to ask is why does ('AA%','AA%') to ('AZ%','AZ%') overlap with ('AA%','BA%') to ('AZ%','BZ%')?

Comment: I think that your design is flawed. What are you trying to achieve with this strange partitioning? I find it hard to imagine a query that would become faster, and it seems unlikely that you want to drop one of these partitions.

Comment: I've created this table just as a testing point for composite keys for table partitioning, Im working with other tables with larges amounts of data that I dont want to touch for now until Im more confidant in how everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular use case, you would have to use subpartitioning:

```
CREATE TABLE part_comp (
   first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   birthday date NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (first_name,last_name)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (last_name);

CREATE TABLE part_comp_a
   PARTITION OF part_comp FOR VALUES FROM ('a') TO ('b')
   PARTITION BY RANGE (first_name);

CREATE TABLE part_comp_b
   PARTITION OF part_comp FOR VALUES FROM ('b') TO ('c')
   PARTITION BY RANGE (first_name);

CREATE TABLE part_comp_a_a
   PARTITION OF part_comp_a FOR VALUES FROM ('a') TO ('b');

CREATE TABLE part_comp_a_b
   PARTITION OF part_comp_a FOR VALUES FROM ('b') TO ('c');

CREATE TABLE part_comp_b_a
   PARTITION OF part_comp_b FOR VALUES FROM ('a') TO ('b');

CREATE TABLE part_comp_b_b
   PARTITION OF part_comp_b FOR VALUES FROM ('b') TO ('c');

...
```

Here it is in action:

```
INSERT INTO part_comp VALUES ('Albert', 'Brein', '2000-02-03');

TABLE part_comp_b_a;

 first_name | last_name |  birthday  
------------+-----------+------------
 Albert     | Brein     | 2000-02-03
(1 row)
```